# Mapbox drawing with snap to grid

Tags: mapbox, mgrs, react

I'm using Mapbox for a web project and would like to have a drawing tool for closed polygons where the drawn line is always snapped to a grid.
Specifically, I'm using a 100m global grid (MGRS) and want for all the drawn shapes to stored by my server as an array of the MGRS grid squares.
Any suggestions either for a drawing tool that is only on the grid lines or for a different way to let users draw a polygon and to turn it into an array of grid squares?